# Complex type checks in XQuery

Tags: xquery, saxon

I have a schema that has many `complexType`, some of which have subtypes (via `xsi:type`). I need to create an `XQuery` expression that checks that an element (`MyPath`) is a member of a parent type, but no others, I've tried an expression in the form below with no luck.

`/MyPath[element(*,ParentClass) and not element(*,ChildClass)]`

It appears `element` applies to all the children in the context it is called, but not itself (`MyPath`), which yields no results.

I also tried the `instance of` operator, but this appears to only work for `simpleType`.

Comment: Is that Saxon EE so that schema-aware XQuery is supported? `instance of` seems to be the right tool https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-instance-of or `typeswitch` https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-typeswitch but that all will only do if you have a schema-aware processor, the right schema import https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-schema-import, the right settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
. instance of element(*, ParentClass) 
and not(. instance of element(*, ChildClass))
```

If this doesn't work please supply an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

An alternative, using Saxon extension functions, is to test the type annotation directly: `saxon:type-annotation(.) eq xs:QName('ParentClass')`

Of course, there's a question about whether this is good practice. The whole point of defining a derived type is that it is supposed to be substitutable for the base type; everywhere you can use an instance of the parent type, you should be able to substitute an instance of the child type. You appear to be deliberately trying to contrive a query in which this is not the case.

Comment: I tried a lazier approach, `. instance of element(*, ParentClass)[not(@xsi:type)]` however, this expression returns no results.

Comment: Are you sure the source document is schema-validated and has type annotations? (I'm only making guesses, in the absence of a repro that's all I can do.)